# Replaced fragment still visible behind new fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to implement an activity which can load different fragments into one container view element. I follow the [Building a Flexible UI Training](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html). Problem: When replacing a fragment, I can still see the replaced fragment in the background.

I see that my question has already been asked numerous times. However all the answers I found seem to be just a workaround (setting the background-color of fragments) or do not apply.

Here is what I have setup so far:

The activity's XML layout contains one FrameLayout as a container for the fragments:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

The id `fragment_container` is used nowhere else in the project.

The complete XML layout of the first fragment:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="First Fragment" />
```

The complete XML layout of the second fragment:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:text="Fragment Second" />
```

The class file of the first fragment looks like this (class for second fragment analogous):

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    public FirstFragment() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    }

}
```

In the activity's onCreate method I load the first fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // load first fragment
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, new FirstFragment())
                .commit();
    }
}
```

When selecting a menu item I try to replace the first fragment with the second fragment with this code in the activity's `onOptionsItemSelected` method:

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new SecondFragment())
        .addToBackStack(null) // <-- does not make any difference if left out
        .commit();
```

The result is that the text "Fragment Second" is printed in red above the text "First Fragment".

What is the "right way" (i.e. not just setting a background-color) to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed this in `onCreate`:

```
        getSupportFragmentManager()
```

and this in `onOptionsItemSelected`:

```
        getFragmentManager()
```

There are actually both versions of the `FragmentManager` in `AppCompatActivity` and they know nothing about each other.  So when you tell `android.app.FragmentManager` to replace a fragment that was added by `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager`, it doesn't know anything about a `FirstFragment` so the operation acts more like an add than a replace.

I've made this mistake more than once.  You'll need to comb through your code and make sure you are consistent about using the support class vs. the regular class.

Comment: It was all because you said the `onOptionsItemSelected` belonged to the activity.  In a fragment, `getFragmentManager()` always does the right thing since the regular fragment only knows about the regular `FragmentManager` and the support fragment only knows about the support one.  If you hadn't said it was the activity's `onOptionsItemSelected`, I would have assumed you were calling it from the fragment, which would not have had any issues.

Comment: Excellent answer!! Kris Larson you saved my day thank you